# Misplaced error message when reviewing close votes

Tags: bug, review, user-interface, error-message, close-dialog

When reviewing close votes, if you click "close" near the top of the page twice, the error message "You may only load the close dialog every 3 seconds." shows by "close" at the bottom of the post, and not by the button that was pressed.

Screenshot:

> [image]

Comment: I took the liberty to add a screenshot hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Your arrows are pointing the wrong way. ;P

Comment: @animuson I'm left handed! :-P

Comment: As long as they're freehand...